# Why do I need to use angular.copy in my factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to have the Thing factory make an HTTP request and be able to use the response in my controller.

1. In my factory I have to do `angular.copy(data, arr)`. Simply doing `arr = data` doesn't work. Why is this? `angular.copy()` just a) deletes everything from `arr` and b) iterates through `data` and assigns stuff to `arr`. The only difference between that and `arr = data` is that `arr` points to `data` rather than a new copy of `data`. Why would this matter? And why doesn't `arr = data.slice(0)` work (from what I understand, it's pretty much the same as `angular.copy)`?
2. What is the best way to accomplish my goal? (use the factory properly)

**main.html**

```
<div class="container">

<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Test App</h1>
</div>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="thing in things">{{thing.name}}</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

**main.controller.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testApp')
  .factory('Thing', function($http) {
    var arr = [];
    return {
      things: arr,
      get: function() {
        $http.get('/api/things').success(function(data) {
          angular.copy(data, arr); // this works
          // arr = data; but this doesn't
          // arr = data.slice(0); and neither does this

        });
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Thing) {
    Thing.get();
    $scope.things = Thing.things;
  });
```

Comment: angular.copy works for Objects or arrays, is data an object by any chance? BTW you should make use of hoisting and extract your anon functions into named functions and simply pass the function name in to the factory and controller method. Makes it much easier to figure out the components of a module.

Comment: `data` is an array of objects.

Comment: It works because arr (array) is a reference, and you need to preserve the reference in order for the scope bindings to work. Otherwise, you are just overwriting arr with a new reference - which is completely different object than the reference that was originally bound to the scope.

Comment: @pixelbits could you elaborate? I thought that scope bindings had to do with $scope itself. How does the factory affect scope bindings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is not related to angular, but to Javascript.

```
var arr = [] // arr is a pointer to an empty array
var things = arr  // things is a pointer to the same empty array
arr = data   // now arr points to data, but things still points to the empty array
```

You can convince yourself of that by running the following code:

```
var a = [1];
var b = a;
a = [2];
// Now if you console.log a and b, a === [2] and b === [1]
```

However if you manipulate the property of an object

```
var a = { data: 1 }
var b = a;
a.data = 2;
// Now a.data and b.data are the same: 2
a = { data: 3 };
// Here we changed a, not its property, so a and b are not the same anymore
// a.data === 3 but b.data === 2
```

If you understand that, there are many ways to solve your issue, such as:

```
angular.module('testApp')
  .factory('Thing', function($http) {
  var obj = {};
  return {
    things: obj,
    get: function() {
      $http.get('/api/things').success(function(data) {
        obj.data = data;
      });
    }
  };
})
```

And in your HTML use `things.data`.

Or if you don't want to use an object property, but directly the array, instead of replacing the pointer you need to only update the content of the array (so arr still points to that same array):

```
angular.module('testApp')
  .factory('Thing', function($http) {
  var arr= [];
  return {
    things: arr,
    get: function() {
      $http.get('/api/things').success(function(data) {
        for (var i in data) {
          arr[i] = data[i];
        }
      });
    }
  };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you set `arr` to some new instance of an array instead of using the current one. Here is an analogy to what you're doing:

```
var foo = function() {
    this.test = 'hello';
    console.log(this.test);
};

foo = function() {
    this.test = 'other';
    console.log(this.test);
};

console.log(foo()); // outputs other
```

angular.copy instead does something like this:

```
// foreach item in the source (in this case data)
arr.push({
   my: "value"
});
```