# weird javascript behavior - logging in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, logging, google-chrome-devtools

I have something really weird going on in my code. An object is sent by the server in a correct way, and it even arrives in my angular factory and i log the object the following shows:

[image: notice how course_id is an integer and 20 when the object is not expanded, when i expand it becomes a string and 19.]

notice how course_id is an integer and 20 when the object is not expanded, when i expand it becomes a string and 19. I am going insane. Has anyone ever had this before? I'm sure there's a reason to this madness!

my angular service:

```
   /*********************************
   * get one batch
   *********************************/

  get: function(batch_id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var request = $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: ENV.api + 'batch/get/' + batch_id,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
    request
      .success(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        deferred.resolve(result);
      })
      .error(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
        deferred.reject(error);
      });

    return deferred.promise;
  },
```

Comment: First thing I noticed was that the `course_id` is displayed as an integer before expanding, and as a string after expanding, so my instinct your bug is related to that. What is the type of `course_id` supposed to be?

Comment: it is supposed to be an integer. The `course_id` is one of my problems, another value that changes is the `end_date`, that's a string value that is contained in the object before i expand it, but becomes empty afterwards

Comment: Can you check to see if this happens in other browsers?

Comment: firefox is fine, safari has the same issue

Comment: Try using `console.log(JSON.parse(result));`, in chrome, do you get the expected output?

Comment: yes, i get the correct object string. I experimented some more and i noticed that it only happens when i assign the data to a scope object

Answer (score 0):

i have figured out a way around it, and a possible answer:

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy](http://angular.copy)

and

[Why do I need to use angular.copy in my factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28378911/why-do-i-need-to-use-angular-copy-in-my-factory)

```
    /*********************************
   * get one batch
   *********************************/

  get: function(batch_id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var request = $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: ENV.api + 'batch/get/' + batch_id,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
    request
      .success(function(result) {
        console.log(angular.copy(result));
        deferred.resolve(angular.copy(result));
      })
      .error(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
        deferred.reject(error);
      });

    return deferred.promise;
  },
```